# semantically replacing unordered list (UL) free text

Tags: html, semantics

I have found validating under HTML5, the validator is throwing up errors for using free text with an unordered list.

EG.

```
<ul>some free text
    <li>1st list item</li>
    <li>2nd list item</li>
</ul>
```

So I have replaced this free text within the 'ul' tag with a HTML5 'figure' tag.

EG.

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>some free text</figcaption>
    <ul>
        <li>1st list item</li>
        <li>2nd list item</li>
    </ul>
</figure>
```

Would you agree that this is semantically correct, or should I be using something else?

Your input is appreciated.

1DMF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me ***Yes*** using `figure` within your code to full fill the purpose is correct...

> [According to w3c](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-figure-element.html#the-figure-element):- The element<sup>(figure)</sup> can thus be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams, photos, code listings, etc, that are referred to from the main content......

Go to *[HTML5 validation service provider](http://html5.validator.nu/)* and enter the below code to confirm its validity....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<figure>
    <figcaption>some free text</figcaption>
    <ul>
        <li>1st list item</li>
        <li>2nd list item</li>
    </ul>
</figure> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Bhavik,     

Thanks for your input, I had already validated the real page in question where I replaced all the ul free text, so I know it validates, I just wanted to be sure it was the semantic thing to do, as valid mark-up != semantic mark-up.

Good to know I was on the right track :-)